# Estimating parameters of sum-stable RV via L-estimators

Tags: distributions, estimation, robust, stable-distribution

One of the purported uses of L-estimators is the ability to 'robustly' estimate the parameters of a random variable drawn from a given class. One of the downsides of using [Levy $\alpha$-stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) is that it is difficult to estimate the parameters given a sample of observations drawn from the class. Has there been any work in estimating parameters of a Levy RV using L-estimators? There is an obvious difficulty in the fact that the PDF and CDF of the Levy distribution do not have a closed form, but perhaps this could be overcome by some trickery. Any hints?

Comment: We need a finite mean (first moment) to compute an L-estimator (don't we?). Levy distributed r.v. do not come with such niceties. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: My understanding is that you need a finite mean to for a population L-*moment* to be defined, but not for the estimands corresponding to all other L-estimators. For example, the sample median is an L-estimator, though it isn't an L-moment.

Answer (score 3):

The Levy distribution has 4 parameter. Each of them has a quantile-based sample equivalent:

1. $\mu$, the location parameter, can be estimated by the median. This is a high efficiency alternative (ARE$\approx 0.85$).
2. $\gamma$, the scale parameter, can be estimated by the median absolute deviation (or more efficiently yet by the Qn estimator (1) with ARE similar to that of the median)
3. $\beta$, the skew parameter, can be estimated by the $S_k$ estimator, with 
   $S_k=(Q_x(\frac{3}{4})-2Q_x(\frac{1}{2})+Q_x(\frac{1}{4}))(Q_x(\frac{3}{4})-Q_x(\frac{1}{4}))^{-1}$ where $Q_x(\tau)$ is the $\tau$^th quantile of $x$.
4. $\alpha$, the tail parameter, can be estimated by Moors's quantile based kurtosis estimator (2).

List of references:

1. P.J. Rousseeuw, C. Croux (1993) Alternatives to the Median
    Absolute Deviation, JASA, *88*, 1273-1283.
2. J. J. A. Moors, (1988) A Quantile Alternative for Kurtosis 
   Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series D (The Statistician)
   Vol. 37, No. 1, pp. 25-32